# How to change the transparent of a UI group overtime?

Tags: unity-game-engine, unity-ui

I want to make a UI group fade out overtime in unity, but have no clue how to do this.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Canvas Group and then change value of alpha from 1 to 0 over time.[Here you can see](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0ownS.png)